# How to get $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2x^2})^2$ from $1+(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2x^2})^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I get $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2x^2})^2$ from $1+(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2x^2})^2$?

The book lists the former as the solution to that step.

This is part of an arc length problem, and I think I'm just hitting a mental roadblock on solving this.

Comment: I mean, how can I make the latter become the former?

Comment: Square them both out using "foil" to see they're equal.

Comment: Irongrave-- seems someone has already actually done all the steps in one of the answers.

Comment: Before expanding, you can save some trouble by factoring out the $1/2$ from the parentheses, and by setting $a=x^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
1 + \left(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2
&=& 1 + \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2 - 2\left(\frac{x^2}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2x^2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2 \\
&=& 1 + \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2 \\
&=& \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2 \\
&=& \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{x^2}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2x^2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2 \\
&=& \left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2x^2}\right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}$$